# Polynomials with coefficients in a field

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's consider this theorem:

> Let $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $p(x)\in F[x]$ with $p(x)\neq 0$. We say $f(x)$ is
>   congruent to $g(x)$ modulo $p(x)$ if $p(x)$ divides $f(x)−g(x)$, and
>   we write $f(x) \equiv g(x) \pmod{p(x)}$

What's the point in assuring that the coefficients of the polynomials belong to $F[x]$ ? Are there some useful properties we can use ?

Comment: That's not a theorem, that's just a definition. It's the results that come from said definition that might be interesting (though they're more often just generalizations of what you've learned for modular congruences with numbers, so in a way not necessarily too surprising).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $F[x]$ is *not* a field; $F$ is. And you must have some set to which all coefficients belong. And it's better that they all belong to the *same* field. Otherwise, what would that definition mean if, say, the coefficients of $f(x)$ belong to $\mathbb C$, whereas the coefficients of $g(x)$ belong to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Why when we work in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$ we can ignore the negative integers ?

Comment: What has that comment to do with my answer?